# upload .jar file and run it. OPENSHIFT

Tags: java, mysql, git, cron, openshift

recently am using Openshift for my graduation project and have created a machine with the following cartridge:
PHP 5.4, MySQL 5.5, phpMyAdmin 4.0, 1.4 Cron

In PHP 5.4 contains a Web page that displays information from the DB.

In the other hand, I have a project in my computer developed in Java that its function is to obtain information from a Web page using an Api and stored in a local database  and I created the .Jar to do ejectuable. Later I export my local database and manually upload OpenShift using Git and finally I import that database to OpenShift.

But I wonder if there is any way to load the .jar file in OpenShift and run through a Cron, so you can store all the information directly into the database OpenShift, and so have everything centralized in the cloud.

I would appreciate your help, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Did you consider using tomcat?
I'm trying something similar to yours:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34735051/jenkins-openshift-gear-run-java-sftp-upload-file